# MySQL entries with self parent_id into sorted cascade array

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, foreach, cascade

I need help with an application I'm creating.

I have a table, looks kind like this:

```
+----+-----------+---------+
| id | parent_id | name    |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 1  | null      | test    |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 2  | null      | test2   |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 4  | 1         | test3   |
+----+-----------+---------+
| 5  | 2         | test4   |
+----+-----------+---------+
```

And now, I get all the data in one array. I would like to get kinda this structure (php array as an cascade):

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => null,
        'name' => 'test',
        'children' => array(
            'id' => 4,
            'parent_id' => 1,
            'name' => 'test3'
        )
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => null,
        'name' => 'test2',
        'children' => array(
            'id' => 5,
            'parent_id' => 2,
            'name' => 'test4'
        )
    )
)
```

So there will every entry with a "parent_id=null" be a parent, and every entry with an id in "parent_id" will be in a child array.

I started it like this:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($names as $name) {
    if($name['parent_id'] == null || $name['parent_id'] == 0) {
        // entry is parent
        $newArray[$name['id']] = $name['name'];
    } else {
        // entry is child
    }
}
```

But here is also my end, I don't know how to do that. I think i have to use some kind of recursive loop function, but I don't know how to start.

Would be awesome if somebody could help me.

Kind regards,
Matt.

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-threaded

Comment: thanks, it helped me a lot. didn't know about this cake feature :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function like this (I only added the code which is relevant for understanding):

```
function get_children($parentId) {
  $array = array();
  //Load/Find $children
  foreach($children as $child) {
    $array[] = array(
      'id' => $child->id,
      'name' => 'YourName',
      'children' => get_children($child->id)
    );
  }
  return $array;
}
```

If you save the data in such an array, it isn't necessary to save the parent_id, because you can get it by searching for the parent elements id.

Comment: Thanks mate, your code works fine!
Just to say, "ndm" showed me, that there is already a CakePHP embedded solution for my problem.